# How is the keccak256(a, b) function implemented?

Tags: solidity, security, hash, keccak, hash-algorithm

I need to understand how keccak256(a, b) is implemented and how it differs from keccak256(a || b).

Is the content padded?

I need this because I do not want to allow for vulnerabilities where a user could fake a hash, for example by doing:
H(0xabc, 0xdef) = H(0xa, 0xbcdef) which would be a major security vulnerability.

Thank you

Comment: I have implemented a short example in Solidity and running keccak256(0xa, 0xa) does not equal keccak256(0xaa). Yet I still need to understand what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity uses a non-standard packed mode where arguments are packed tightly. You can check out the algorithm in the docs: [Solidity: non-standard-packed-mode](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode)

In summary,  `keccak256(a,b) = keccak(a || b)` is given.
You might wonder why your example `keccak256(0xa, 0xa) ≠ keccak256(0xaa)` seems to prove my thesis wrong. This is simply because you tried to use a datatype that is unknown in Solidity. In Solidity numbers are stored in a multiple of 8 bits. You tried to use a number containing only 4 bits, leading to a situation where the Solidity compiler is being forced to pad your number to fit into 8 bits. `0xa` became `0x0a` for example. So you tried to compare `keccak256(0xa, 0xa) = keccak256(0x0a, 0x0a) = keccak256(0x0a0a)` with `keccak256(0xaa)`

Comment: This means that if you want to avoid padding attacks, you need to make sure that your variables have the correct lengths such that no variable can "overflow" onto the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the new [abi.encodePacked](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-functions) when more than a single parameter to `keccak256`

> These encoding functions can be used to craft data for function calls without actually calling a function. Furthermore, `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b))` is a more explicit way to compute `keccak256(a, b)`, which will be deprecated in future versions.